# clang W flag order

Tags: c++, clang++

I have noticed a funny behavior with clang (I use 3.6.0), and I have not found any reference about it in the documentation or anywhere else. Here is a small example:

```
int main(){
    int a;
    return 0;
}
```

I compile it with `clang++ -Wall -W -Werror -Wno-error=unused-variable main.cpp` and I have the expected warning:

```
main.cpp:2:9: warning: unused variable 'a' [-Wunused-variable]
    int a;
1 warning generated.
```

Now, let's try `clang++ -Werror -Wno-error=unused-variable -Wall -W main.cpp`

```
main.cpp:2:9: error: unused variable 'a' [-Werror,-Wunused-variable]
    int a;
1 error generated.
```

Have I missed something? Is it expected? For that matters, gcc compiles both lines.

Comment: Your first example should be an error since you have  `-Werror` no?

Comment: @NathanOliver no, since he specifies `-Wno-error=unused-variable`.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant thanks for that.  my brain was seeing `-Werro` for some reason.

Comment: @NathanOliver no problem. It's indeed there, but the `-Wno-error=` flag should in principle override it for special cases.

Comment: It will also just issue a warning when using `clang++ -Wall -Werror -Wno-error=unused-variable -W main.cpp`.  [live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d1d0e03d0a4cf188)

Comment: It might be a false negative triggered by a bug in the order `-Wno-error` and then `-Wall`. The extensive and complete diagnostics `-Weverything` (clang only) [works as expected](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c4cc3836a53f16fe)

Comment: @MarcoA. good catch indeed! I'll report that to llvm

Comment: For anyone interested in the progress: https://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=24376 (it would be kind not to rep**ore as soon as an answer is posted and give OP a chance to post an answer himself).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I was answered:

> I think that the better title would be that -Wno-error is position dependent on the command line while -Werror is not.  The important part is whether the diagnostic is an error or a warning.  With the example:

```
int main() {
  int a;
  return 0;
}

$ clang main.cpp -Wunused-variable
```

> This gives an unused variable warning.

```
$ clang main.cpp -Werror -Wunused-variable
$ clang main.cpp -Wunused-variable -Werror
```

> Both of these give an unused variable error.  -Werror does not change
>   behavior based on position.

```
$ clang main.cpp -Werror -Wno-error=unused-variable -Wunused-variable
$ clang main.cpp -Werror -Wunused-variable -Wno-error=unused-variable
```

> The first gives an error while the second gives an warning.  This
>   means that -Wno-error=* is position dependent.  (GCC will issue
>   warnings for both of these lines.)
>
> -Werror does not interact or depend on the warnings on the command line.
>   -Wno-error=warning does depend on its relative position to -Wwarning.

Which I'm perfectly fine with. It just should be written somewhere (I may have missed it!)